# Repeating Mail Calendar Reminders?

Tags: calendar, email, ms-office, reminders

We have an iPhone 3G running iOS 5.0.1 (9A405), which connects to an Exchange server in Mail.

Calendar is synced, and event reminders pop up with an alarm on the phone.  The alarm occurs once only.

**Is there any way to set the alarm/reminder to repeat?**

Is this set on the phone, or in Outlook when creating the calendar event?  I can't see an option for this in Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**:  If you're connecting an Exchange account or to a Google calendar via the Exchange setting, the Second Alert option is not available, because these systems do not support a second alert.

If you are not connecting via the Exchange setting you can access the Second Alert like this:

- On your iPhone, start Calendar.
- Navigate to the day that has your event.
- Select the event, which brings up the Event Details.
- Click the Edit button.
- Scroll down until you see Alert.
- If the event does not already have an alert, it will say "none" and you click "none" to add an alert.
- Once the event has an alert, you will see a new entry just below it called Second Alert.  It will say "none" and just like the first alert, you can click on it to add another alert.

Comment: Thanks mate; I've added an alert to a test event (which originally had none), but no new field called "second alert" appears afterwards. Test phone is iOS v5.0.1 (9A405). Ideally we want to set this up in Outlook so a PA can do this for a GM. Thanks.

Comment: Let me Google this for you.  It seems that since Outlook/Exchange does not support a second alert, Apple doesn't support it either.  Events synced to a Google calendar have the same issue.  Sorry.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.